# How to exclude a folder from my htaccess command

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have the followind htaccess in my main root... but I want to exclude a subdomain folder to install a wordpress... actually the wordpress im trying to install is giving error ,, when I remove this htaccess the wordpress works fine... thanks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ok here is http://pastebin.com/u8qdGHqq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude a file from htaccess, you can place an htaccess file in the directory with a simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Otherwise, in the root folder's htaccess file, you can add this right below the `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^directory_you_want_to_protect - [L]
```

But I suspect that this is really a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. You're probably going to need to rework or combine the htaccess rules that wordpress requires with the ones that you have right now. They may not be entirely compatible. If it's a matter not being able to run the *installer*, simply remove the root's htaccess file temporarily, install wordpress, then figure out how to combine the rules.

Comment: @user1596253 Yes, and I've described exactly how in my answer, even given you 2 different ways to do it.

Comment: Yes it works perfect! no need for install the wordpress first.. thanks